# BigQuery - Create a view with a REPEATED RECORD field

Tags: google-bigquery

How can I create aview in BigQuery with a schema having:

```
field_V_1 string NULLABLE
field_V_2 string NULLABLE
field_V_3 RECORD NULLABLE
field_V_3.field_V_4 string NULLABLE
field_V_3.field_V_5 string NULLABLE
field_V_6 RECORD REPEATED 
field_V_6.field_V_7 string REPEATED
```

from an existing table having:

```
field_T_1 string
field_T_2 string
field_T_3 string
field_T_4 string
field_T_5 string REPEATED
```

For now, I tried:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `<someviewname>` AS
select field_T_1, field_T_2,
STRUCT(field_T_3 as field_V_4,field_T_4 as field_V_5) as field_V_3,
STRUCT(field_T_5 as field_V_7) as  field_V_6 
from `<sourcetable>`
```

But this gives me:

```
field_V_6 RECORD NULLABLE  =======> instead of RECORD REPEATED
field_V_6.field_V_7 string REPEATED
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using square brackets like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `<someviewname>` AS
SELECT 
  field_T_1,
  field_T_2,
  STRUCT(field_T_3 as field_V_4, field_T_4 as field_V_5) as field_V_3,
  [STRUCT(field_T_5 as field_V_7)] as field_V_6 
FROM `<sourcetable>`
```

or

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `<someviewname>` AS
SELECT 
  field_T_1,
  field_T_2,
  STRUCT(field_T_3 as field_V_4, field_T_4 as field_V_5) as field_V_3,
  [STRUCT([field_T_5] as field_V_7)] as field_V_6 
FROM `<sourcetable>`
```